# add a reference to a visual studio project for amazon web services sdk

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, amazon-web-services, projects-and-solutions

**how can I add a reference to the amazon sdk (installed already) to my existing class library?**

I can make a new amazon aws project, but I just want to add a reference to an already existing class library which will use amazon aws API's.

searched on line, but could not find it... so a link is as good as a direct answer.

Comment: If you have the SDK, you just add a ref to AWSSDK.DLL.

Comment: i kinda figured that, but how exactly? i go to references and then add reference (on right click) but can not find amazon in the lists.

Comment: you need to click browse, and find it on your harddrive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the existing class library dll? I strongly engcourage you to download and install NuGet from Tools > Extension Manager and use that to install third party libraries. Check out the NuGet [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/) for more details :)

To install (and reference) the AWS SDK, run the following command from the Package Manager Console:

> Install-Package AWSSDK